# Building lists based on matched attributes (ansible)

Tags: linux, ansible

Trying to build a list of servers that match an attribute (in this case and ec2_tag) to schedule specific servers for specific tasks.

I'm trying to match against `selectattr` with:

```
servers: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]|selectattr('ec2_tag_Role', 'match', 'cassandra_db_seed_node') | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') |list}}"
```

Though I'm getting what looks like a type error from Ansible:

```
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]|selectattr('ec2_tag_Role', 'match', 'cassandra_db_seed_node') | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') |list}}): expected string or buffer"}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Also just to clarify I've used the above syntax before and it worked, this seems particularly related to the type of object produced by hostvars[inventory_hostname]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`group_by`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/group_by_module.html) module to create ad-hoc groups depending on the hostvar:

```
- group_by:
    key: 'ec2_tag_role_{{ ec2_tag_Role }}'
```

This will create groups called `ec2_tag_role_*` which means that later on you can create a play with any of these groups:

```
- hosts: ec2_tag_role_cassandra_db_seed_node
  tasks:
    - name: Your tasks...
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked for me:
`- group_by:
    key: "ec2_tag_role_{{ ec2_tag_Role }}"
- debug: msg="{{groups.ec2_tag_role_cassandra_db_seed_node|join(', ')}}"`

Answer (score 5):

When you build a complex filter chain, use `debug` module to print intermediate results... and add filter one by one to achieve desired result.

In your example, you have mistake on the very first step: `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` is a dict of facts for your current host only, so there is nothing to select elements from.

You need a list of `hostvars`' values, because `selectattr` is applied to a list, not a dict.

But in Ansible `hostvars` is a special variable and is not actually a dict, so you can't just call `.values()` on it without jumping through some hoops.

Try the following code:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: a kind of typecast for hostvars
      set_fact:
        hostvars_dict: "{{ hostvars }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars_dict.values() | selectattr('ec2_tag_Role','match','cassandra_db_seed_node') | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') | list }}"
```

Comment: Gave this a vote up cause it does explain that `hostvars` is a special variable which can help people understand why `selectattr` is not working but the above code gave me the original error. Though it does seem to wrap everything with an array.